# Unary plus for S4 class in R

Tags: r, operator-overloading, r-s4, unary-operator

I am experimenting with S4 classes in R and I was trying to define a plus (`+`) operator for my objects, i.e. overload the plus operator. I managed to overload the binary `+`, but I cannot figure out how to overload the unary plus. Here is a minimal working (*unary operator not working*) example for what I am trying to achieve:

```
setClass("HWtest",
         representation(expr  = "character"),
         prototype = list(expr  = NA_character_)
)

H <- new("HWtest", expr="Hello")
W <- new("HWtest", expr="World")

setMethod("+", signature(e1="HWtest", e2="HWtest"),
          function(e1,e2){
            new("HWtest", 
                expr = paste(e1@expr," + ",e2@expr))
          }
)
```

Now I can use the `+` operator and it works smoothly:

```
H+W
An object of class "HWtest"
Slot "expr":
[1] "Hello  +  World"
```

Now the unary plus of course doesn't work, so that has to be overloaded

```
+H
Error in +H : invalid argument to unary operator
```

So I tried to overload it in the following way:

```
setMethod("+", signature(e="HWtest"),
          function(e){
            new("HWtest", 
                expr = paste("+ ",e@expr))
          }
)
```

But this generates the error:

```
Error in match.call(fun, fcall) : 
  argument 1 matches multiple formal arguments
```

Is it possible to overload the unary plus? If so, how would I do it for this minimal example?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try adding this (in addition to your binary overload):

```
setMethod("+", signature(e1 = "HWtest", e2 = "missing"),
          function(e1){
            new("HWtest", 
                expr = paste("+ ", e1@expr))
          }
)
```

---

```
R> +H
An object of class "HWtest"
Slot "expr":
[1] "+  Hello"

R> H + W
An object of class "HWtest"
Slot "expr":
[1] "Hello  +  World"
```

---

Citing the help file `?groupGeneric`,

> [...] when a unary operator is encountered the Ops method is called
>   with one argument and e2 is missing.

And as Frank points out, the `?setMethod` help file contains some useful information regarding the use of `missing` as a method signature (emphasis added):

> Two additional special class names can appear: "ANY", meaning that
>   this  argument can have any class at all; **and "missing", meaning that
>   this argument  must not appear in the call in order to match this
>   signature.**

Comment: I think `?setMethod` is also useful, where it explains how to indicate that an arg is missing, like `"missing", meaning that this argument must not appear in the call in order to match this signature.`

Comment: Ok this clarifies it for me! Thanks a lot guys :)